# Ionic2 Cordova Camera Not Working

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/04/use-the-device-camera-in-an-ionic-2-android-and-ios-app/) that outlines a very simple camera app on iOS. I can build successfully using `ionic build ios` and can open it in XCode with no warnings or errors. I'm able to deploy to my iPhone 7, and while it successfully shows the splash screen, it just shows a blank white screen after.

**src/pages/home/home.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Camera} from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
    public base64Image: string;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.base64Image = "https://placehold.it/150x150";
    }

    public takePicture() {
        Camera.getPicture({
                quality : 75,
                destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit : true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 300,
                targetHeight: 300,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        }).then(imageData => {
                this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, error => {
                console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
}
```

**src/pages/home/home.html:**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
            Ionic 2 Camera
        </ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button (click)="takePicture()">
                <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <img src="{{ base64Image }}" />
</ion-content>
```

My `ionic info` output:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.4 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.5.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

I've also tried adding notes in the Camera/Photo privacy keys in the info.plist when I'm in XCode but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: are you sure its related to plugin? any console errors in `ionic serve`?

Comment: Ugh good call... it's saying it can't find ionic-native. I just tried ionic-native/core and @ionic-native but that doesn't work either... how do I install ionic-native? Shouldn't that be... native?

Comment: which version of ionic native you have installed? can you add package.json to question?

Comment: I was able to get it installed... do you want to submit the ionic serve suggestion as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Alright..done..glad you got it resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

`ionic serve -l`

in order to get the console.log errors.
Or in case of emulator you can use [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) in **Chrome developer tools**